# function _readOnlyError(name)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, babeljs, eslint

I'm trying to do some authentication of a JWT, but I get this error:

```
api\utils\index.js:16
function _readOnlyError(name) { throw new Error("\"" + name + "\" is read-only"); }
```

and I don't understand why.

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config();

export const jwtToken = {
  createToken({ id, email }) {
    return jwt.sign(
      { id, email },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: '24h' }
    );
  },
  verifyToken(token) {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '24h' });
    return decoded;
  }
};


export const hashPassword = (hashPassword) = (password) => bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
export const comparePassword = (password, hash) => bcrypt.compareSync(password, hash);
```

Comment: What is the `stack` of your error? It should point you to what the original line of code is that caused the issue.

Comment: Error: "hashPassword" is read-only. I comment the line with const hashPassword and it's works i will work on it. thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see your typo. You have `export const hashPassword = (hashPassword) = (password) => bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
` which is doing an assignment to `hashPassword` twice. You probably just want `export const hashPassword = (password) => bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);`

Comment: Yes, that it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Related issue, with an example:

Code:

```
let obj1 = { Key: "key1" };

const { Key } = obj1;               // NOTE - Key is constant (`const`)

if (!Key) {
    Key = "key2";                   // NOTE - Key is constant (`const`) but overwritten
}
```

Error:

```
{"stack":"Error: \"Key\" is read-only\n    at _readOnlyError ... }
```

Solution:

```
let { Key, Other } = obj1;          // NOTE - Now Key is  not constant (`let`)
```